# Script to morph between two objects in Blender

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers, vertices, blender-internal-render-engine

I am trying to write a script that will morph one of my object (say a sphere) into another object (say a cube). As my sphere and cube have different number of vertices, I tried to downsample the object with more vertices using decimate modifier so that the two matches. Then I interpolate between the original vertices coordinates and the target vertices coordinates to control the degree of morph between the two. However, in this way what I get out is a half sphere and half cube thing instead of a morph between the two. Any one has any idea what's wrong with my method? Or does there exist scripts/functions that can do morphing between two objects in blender?

'''

```
 original_verts = bpy.data.objects[x].data.vertices #get the vertices of my original object x
 target_verts = bpy.data.objects[y].data.vertices #get the vertices of my target object y
 original_vert_range = range(0, len(vertices), 1)
 target_vert_range = range(0, len(new_verts), 1)

 obj = bpy.data.objects[x]
 dm = obj.modifiers.new('Decimate', 'DECIMATE')
 dm.ratio = len(target_verts)/len(original_verts) #no.vertices in target is smaller than in the original object
 bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier='Decimate')

 for i in original_vert_range:
       vertex = original_verts[i]
       origin = vertex.co.copy()  
       vertex.co = origin.lerp(target_verts[i].co, 1)
```

'''

Thanks so much!

Comment: Ref: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/262094/how-can-i-transform-my-coffee-cup-into-a-torus-as-seen-on-wikipidea/262174#262174

Comment: Sphere and cube seem OK, but what do you do when you have a sandal and a pineapple?.. I don't think you can write a script for that.